# Getting values of dynamically created PageLoad Controls in ButtonClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, web

I am trying to create a page for store where there is a dropdown list which shows Seller's name and when the name is selected it shows the respective products the seller is selling in checkbox list and in text box the store owner can write that how many quantities have been sold so that it can be updated back in database.
[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lazVw.png)

The problem I am facing is I have to add as many textboxes as the products in the checkbox list so I am adding them in while statement where I am adding items to the list. I have to add them in pageLoad because I want them to appear in front of checkbox list as soon as the seller's name is selected from the dropdown list. 
Now I want to get the quantity written in those textboxes when the button is clicked. but I am initializing the textbox in PageLoad and have to the the use it's value in Button_Clicked.
What should I do? How can I get the value from textbox in buttonclick event?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Database_Table
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection conn = new       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string seller = "select * from [Product] where s_id='"+SellerList.SelectedValue+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(seller,conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            product_list.Items.Clear();
            int number = 0;
            while(myreader.Read()){
                ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                newItem.Text = myreader["p_name"].ToString();
                newItem.Value = myreader["p_id"].ToString();
                product_list.Items.Add(newItem);

                //TextBox Add-------------------------
                var txt = new TextBox();
                txt.ID = "textbox" + number;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
                //------------------------------------


                //Label Add--------------------------
                var lbl1 = new Label();
                lbl1.ID = "label_" + number++;
                lbl1.Text = "Quantity: ";
                Panel2.Controls.Add(lbl1);
                //------------------------------------
            }
            conn.Close();

    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();


                foreach (ListItem item in product_list.Items)
                {
                    int number_1 = 0;
                    if (item.Selected == true)
                    {
                        Response.Write(product_list.SelectedItem);
                        string quantity = "select p_qty from [Product] where p_id=" + item.Value;
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(quantity, conn);
                        string quan_str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        int quan_int = Int32.Parse(quan_str);
                        int updated_quan = quan_int;


                        //Label-------------------------------
                        var lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.ID = "label" + number_1++;
                        lbl.Text = "Quantity left of " + item.Text + ": " + updated_quan + "\n" + Environment.NewLine;
                        Panel3.Controls.Add(lbl);
                        //-----------------------------------

                        //Quantity Upadte Query---------------
                        string quan_up = "update [Product] set p_qty=@qty where p_id=@id";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(quan_up, conn);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.Value);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", updated_quan);
                        int q = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //-----------------------------------
                    }
                }
        }
    }


}
 }
```

And one more thing, can anyone identify why my
     `if (item.Selected == true)` statement is not working?
I have to make it `false` and then whether I select any value or not all values get selected?

Comment: Alright everyone, did it by using

    TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)FindControl("textbox"+number_1);
and accessed it's value by

    string temp = txtAddress.Text;

Comment: But still why this if statement is not working?`if (item.Selected == true)`